# Why doesn't android like the \?

Tags: java, android, substring

I'm working in android studio 1.1.0 and I am trying to remove all of the \ and \n from a string but the IDE doesn't seem to recognize it as a string when I put it in "" it is blue instead of green like a normal string and it doesn't work out in my code any ideas? I'm testing it on an actual api15 device.

```
 int i= string.indexOf("\")
string.substring(0, i)
```

Something like that is what I tried

Comment: what have u tried? Post some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The back-slash `\` is used to escape some special chars in a string such as quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`), etc.

If you want to use it in a string, do it like this : `"\\"`

Read the [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) section from the doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In java the "\" is called an escape character. It does different things based on the following character. For example:

\n = new line

\t = tab or 5 spaces

If you just want to use "\" then use "\".
So, you would want to do something like this:

int i= string.indexOf("\");